# deleting mySQL duplicates from a table. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete duplicate mySQL records where the `name` is the same. I found this solution from someone else here (yes, i searched before!) but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
DELETE FROM db_products USING db_products, db_products e1
WHERE db_products.id > e1.id
AND db_products.name = e1.name
```

I also tried `product_id` instead of `id` because my unique IDs are called that, but it's also throwing a mySQL error.

Comment: Provide some sample data and the DDL.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a temporary table and add the distinct values from your original table

> SELECT DISTINCT * INTO db_products_temp FROM db_products;

After verifying it, drop the original table and rename the temp table to db_products.

Comment: can you drop the original in all cases ?

Comment: depends on your need actually. If you feel that the original is not valid then you might as well drop it. If it is needed then either back it up or rename it.

Comment: cool thing is doing it with Alter Table, locking, quick, a DDL change that is a hot swap ! Which was pointed out to to me unbeknownst to me. In fact most things are unbeknownst to me :>  Percona [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/11/18/avoiding-mysql-alter-table-downtime/)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many records which will satisfy condition "db_products.id > e1.id". Thats  why all the duplicates will not be deleted.
Try below query. This might help.

```
    DELETE FROM db_products USING db_products, db_products e1
    WHERE max(db_products.id) > e1.id
    AND db_products.name = e1.name 
    group by db_products.id;
```